# Activator.CreateInstance causing nunit to lock which prevents visual studio building

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, activator

After I run my test that runs my suspect code; I cannot rebuild the assembly in Visual Studio until Nunit (or more specifically nunit-agent.exe) is ended.

The error is:

```
Could not copy "C:\path\MyTests\MyTests.dll" to "bin\Debug\MyTests.dll". 
    Exceeded retry count of 10.
Unable to copy file "C:\path\MyTests\Debug\MyTests.dll" 
    to "bin\Debug\MyTests.dll". The process cannot access the file 
    'bin\Debug\MyTests.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

Current workaround is to close nunit, rebuild and then reopen nunit (and then test). *painful*

**The red-herring was thinking this was a Volume Shadow Copy issue or a project base path setting in the nunit project. It is not these. It is this code.**

```
AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some");
string fullPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
                  .Replace("file:///", "").Replace("/", "\\");
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
assemblyName.CodeBase = fullPath;
Assembly assembly = dom.Load(assemblyName);
Type type = assembly.GetType("ClassName");

IMyInterface obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IMyInterface;

obj.ActionMessage(param1, param2);
```

I thought this was a disposal problem, so I implemented IDisposable and added the required code to the class "ClassName". Did not work.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: You got this [same error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229688/495455) last year. Some other possible dup's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182841/nunit-locking-dll and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851751/nunit-vs2010-unable-to-copy-file-from-obj-to-bin-being-used-by-another-p

Comment: as i said in my post, it is not either of those issues. It has to do with the CreateInstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to execute

```
AppDomain.Unload(dom);
```

Full method:

```
public static object InstObject(Assembly ass, string className)
{
    AppDomain dom = null;
    try
    {
        Evidence evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);

        string fullPath = ass.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "").Replace("/", "\\");
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
        assemblyName.CodeBase = fullPath;
        dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain", evidence, 
                 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                 System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fullPath), true);

        Assembly assembly = dom.Load(assemblyName);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className);

        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        return obj;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dom != null) AppDomain.Unload(dom);
    }
}
```